# Not successfully in appending an element to the list (Python)

Tags: python, list, append

Not sure why the append function returns 'None" in following code

```
dw=[1,3,5]
dw=[0]+dw
print(dw,type(dw))
dw=dw.append(12)
print(dw)
```

Output is: ([0, 1, 3, 5],'list'), None.

Why not [0,1,3,5,12] with append function?

Thanks;

Comment: Because `.append` doesn’t return anything. Remove `dw=`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to a list accessing the `append` method. The `append` method does not return anything.

```
dw=[1,3,5]
dw=[0]+dw
print(dw,type(dw))
dw.append(12) #here, just call append and not assign it to a variable
print(dw)
```

Comment: Looks like a stupid error. Thanks!

Comment: @kaneroy Glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!